# Loading multiple elements after HttpClient get in angular

Tags: angular, rxjs

So I have the following JSON comming from an API.

```
[{
  groupName: "someName",
  groupDescription: "someDescription",
  items: ["id1", "id2", "id3"]
}, {...}]
```

And what I want to ending up with the full items also called from the API.

So I thinking on doing

- Calling API with httpClient.get to receive the initial JSON
- Use rxjs operators to do a forkJoin of all the items id for each row
- Join everything together to end up with a JSON like the following.

  [{
    "groupName": "someName",
    "groupDescription": "someDescription",
    "items": [{ id: "id1", name: "item1 name" }, { id: "id2", name: "item2 name" }]
  }]

I'm struggeling to find the correct operators to merge everything this way.

Comment: Can you use lodash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can map the `forkJoin` result into the original response. For example like the following:

```
this.httpClient.get(...)
  .pipe(
    mergeMap(response => {
      const observables = response.items.map(id => this.httpClient.get(`.../${id}`));

      return forkJoin(...observables).pipe(
        map(items => {
          response.items = items;
          return response;
        }),
      );
    }),
  )
  .subscribe(...)
```

Maybe you'll want to use `mergeAll` right after the first `this.httpClient.get(...)` to flatten the response where each object will be emitted as a separate emission. Then at the and use `toArray()` to make one large array of objects.